# Godot Dash Function

Tags: godot

So, the code I have for a dash function is not working correctly even though im positive the logic is correct. I suspected the problem was with the variable isdashing so I printed out the value for it and comes back false no matter what I do. Can anyone tell me what im doing wrong?

```
extends KinematicBody2D

export(int) var Jump_Height = -100
export(int) var Jump_Realese = -60
export(int) var gravity = 4

var velocity = Vector2.ZERO

var move_speed = 50
#Jump Stuff
var max_jump = 2
var jump_count = 0
# Dash Stuff
var dash_direction = Vector2(1,0)
var dashable = false
var isdashing = false



# Movement 
func _physics_process(delta):
    dash()
    gravity_control()
    

    if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_right"):
        velocity.x = move_speed
    elif Input.is_action_pressed("ui_left"):
        velocity.x = -move_speed
    else:
        velocity.x = 0  
    if is_on_floor() and jump_count != 0:
        jump_count = 0  
    
    if jump_count<max_jump:
        if Input.is_action_just_pressed("ui_up"):
            velocity.y = Jump_Height    
            jump_count += 1
    else:
        if Input.is_action_just_released("ui_up") and velocity.y < Jump_Realese:
            velocity.y = Jump_Realese
        
    velocity = move_and_slide(velocity, Vector2.UP)

func dash():
    if is_on_floor():
        dashable = true
        
    if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_left"):
        dash_direction = Vector2(-1,0)
    if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_right"):
        dash_direction = Vector2(1,0)
        
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("ui_Dash") and dashable:
        velocity = dash_direction.normalized() * 7000
        dashable = false
        isdashing = true
        yield(get_tree().create_timer(0.2), "timeout")
        isdashing = false
```

Comment: First thing to come to mind is to double check the input mapping for `"ui_Dash"`. Second add a breakpoint where you set `isdashing = true` so you can confirm the execution reaches that point. Finally a hunch: is `is_on_floor` returning true? Try calling `dash` at the end of `_physics_process` instead of the start, just in case the problem is that `is_on_floor` is not giving you the updated value.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that `Input.is_action_just_pressed("ui_Dash")` is false because `dash()` is being called in the physics_process function which doesn't run every frame (it runs 60 times a second).

What currently happens is -

1. During a game frame, the user presses the dash button.  At this point Input.is_action_just_pressed("ui_Dash") is true but nothing has checked it.
2. A frame or two (or more) later, the dash function is called in the physics_process.  This polls if the dash button was just pressed - but now it's false because it was "just pressed" a few frames ago, not on this frame.

The only way your current logic works is if the dash button was pressed in the EXACT frame that the physics_process runs.

You can get around this by using Input.is_action_pressed("ui_Dash") to capture the button press, setting a flag to prevent it being captured on the next physics frame and then enabling it again sometime later.  E.g.

```
var can_dash: boolean = true

func dash():
    if is_on_floor():
        dashable = true
        
    if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_left"):
        dash_direction = Vector2(-1,0)
    if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_right"):
        dash_direction = Vector2(1,0)
        
    if can_dash and Input.is_action_pressed("ui_Dash") and dashable:
        can_dash = false;
        velocity = dash_direction.normalized() * 7000
        dashable = false
        isdashing = true
        yield(get_tree().create_timer(0.2), "timeout")
        isdashing = false
        can_dash = true
```

Answer (score 0):

You are resetting your variables (especially velocity) **before** calling move_and_slide().

Solution: Call dash() immediately before calling move_and_slide().

This is the reset I'm referring to:

```
if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_right"):
        velocity.x = move_speed
    elif Input.is_action_pressed("ui_left"):
        velocity.x = -move_speed
    else:
        velocity.x = 0
```